# Split content into pages MVC 4 Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to split content into pages and I am looking for the smartest way. So my controller send a model with for example 45 records I want to display them in 3 pages with 15 rows in each one of them with navigation buttons in the bottom.([1] , [2] ... like links) What should I do? Split the content in the controller and make 3 separates views with different names for example `/Home/Action/page1`....
`/Home/Action/page2` ? Or there is smarter way to do this.

Comment: are you looking for somethink like grid

Comment: This question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070030/the-easiest-way-for-paging-with-mvc3-c

Comment: Actually i can't use it as i expected... Is there a tutorial how to make it work i mean to display the content end to end tutorial... Because in the other question there's only the view code... And i'am encountering some problems implementing logic in controller maybe I should add some things in the model i don't know... I managed to display pages but only with the content from page 1.....

Answer (score 2):

I got found what i was looking for here: [Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application (3 of 10)](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).